# SQL Unpivot with row numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a SELECT statement with UNPIVOT

```
SELECT dycd_acnam, dycd_dynam, dycd_value
FROM GCATT.dbo.tblDaycode UNPIVOT (
dycd_value FOR dycd_dynam IN (
    Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday)
) AS pvtDaycode
GROUP BY dycd_acnam, dycd_dynam, dycd_value
```

And returns values like

```
dycd_acnam  |  dycd_dynam  |  dycd_value
----------------------------------------
MT          | Monday       | 1
MT          | Tuesday      | 1
MT          | Wednesday    | 0
MT          | Thursday     | 0
```

How can I add a row number before the row `dycd_acnam`? Tried `RANK()` but it returned wrong values. I want to avoid using #Temp tables as much as possible.

Comment: How is the `row_number` to be calculated?

Comment: Sequentially. Like an identity row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want an incrementing column added to the result you can add

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
```

to the `SELECT` list

Comment: Wow. Neat and simple. Thanks a lot mate! :D