# Is it possible to transpose a table's entries and store it into a temp table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to transpose the data from my table and do some plottings into powerBI.

Here is how I feel up my database from my application:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO PoD_NewPriceList_Data
                                        (ID, Product_Barcode, Product_Name,
                                         Store_Price, Internet_Price, InsertDate)
                        VALUES (@ID, @Product_Barcode, @Product_Name,
                                @Store_Price, @Internet_Price, @InsertDate)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("Product_Barcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = barcode;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Product_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PriceList.name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Store_Price", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble(storePrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Internet_Price", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble(PriceList.price, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("InsertDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = InsertDate.AddDays(2);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = barcode.GetHashCode();

    result = result && (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0);
}
```

And in SQL Server Management Studio here is how my table looks like:

```
SELECT 
    [ID], [Product_Barcode], [Product_Name],
    [Store_Price], [Internet_Price], [InsertDate]
FROM 
    [dbo].[PoD_NewPriceList_Data]
```

and I get the following output:

[image]

The main issue is when trying to create the plots as requested in PowerBI I need my data to look as follows:

```
                    F5321
    Product_Name    Sony Xperia...
    Store_Price     399
    Internet_Price  327.51
    InsertDate      2017.04.27
```

Any help would be well appreciated.

Comment: which plot in Power BI do you want to use?

Comment: Line Chart or Line and clustered column Chart. I Need to plot the InsertDate on the X axis, product Name or Barcode could be clustered Column and both the Store Price and Internet Price as Lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and modify this SQL script. I use `@t` table variable, replace it with your table name `[PoD_NewPriceList_Data]`.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
id int,
product_barcode varchar(max),
product_name varchar(max),
store_price int,
internet_price decimal,
insert_date date
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1,'F5321', 'Sony Xperia', 399, 255.1, '2017-04-25')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2,'F5833', 'Sony Xperia XZ', 458, 398.2, '2017-04-26')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (3,'F5121', 'Sony Xperia XA Rose', 161, 155.6, '2017-04-27')

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Unpivoted') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #Unpivoted
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Transposed') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #Transposed

/* Unpivot table to get rows instead of columns */
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as rn
INTO #Unpivoted
FROM (SELECT product_barcode, product_name, 
      CAST(store_price as varchar(max))  store_price,
      CAST(internet_price as varchar(max))  internet_price, 
      CAST(insert_date as varchar(max)) as insert_date
      FROM @t) src
UNPIVOT (
    value FOR field IN (
        product_barcode, product_name, store_price, internet_price, insert_date
    )
) unpiv

CREATE TABLE #Transposed 
(Field varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL )

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE #Transposed ADD item' + 
    RIGHT('000' + CAST(sv.number AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) + ' varchar(max) '
    FROM [master].dbo.spt_values sv
    WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
        AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '') 

Exec(@SQL)  /* Dynamically create columns */

INSERT INTO #Transposed (Field)  SELECT DISTINCT Field FROM #Unpivoted 
/*populate field names*/
DECLARE @fieldCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Transposed)

/* using rn to filter proper record from transposed table */
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    UPDATE #Transposed SET item' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(sv.number AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) 
    + ' = up.value FROM #Transposed t  CROSS APPLY 
    ( SELECT TOP 1 u.value FROM  #unpivoted u WHERE u.field = t.field AND u.rn > ' 
    + CAST((sv.number-1)*@fieldCount AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ORDER BY rn) up  '
      FROM [master].dbo.spt_values sv
      WHERE sv.[type] = 'p'
        AND sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t)
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '') 

Exec(@SQL)  /*Dynamically fill in values */

SELECT t.* FROM #Transposed t 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 rn FROM #Unpivoted u WHERE u.field=t.field) up
ORDER BY up.rn ASC  /* add a link to Unpivoted to fix the item order */

DROP TABLE #Unpivoted
DROP TABLE #Transposed
```

It does what you need in several steps

1. converts columns to rows with [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx). Watch that you have to CAST all the values to the exactly same type. Adds a row number to filter the rows in step 3.
2. creates a temp table with dynamic number of columns corresponding to the number of rows
3. fills in the columns names into rows into the dynamically created table
4. fills in values into the dynamically created table

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002056/2224701) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645062/2224701).

Of course the number of columns is limited here, so if you try to convert  many rows into columns, you get:

> Cannot create a row of size 8066 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060.

Comment: Hallo @Vojtěch Donal i finally got something from your post , thanks a lot